# Error when getting array of dates with current date from array of dates

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdate, nspredicate

I have an NSMutableArray "NewDate" with NSDate objects

```
(
"2013-08-11 20:26:11 +0000",
"2013-08-11 20:26:11 +0000",
"2013-08-12 06:22:38 +0000",
"2013-08-12 07:24:14 +0000",
"2013-08-12 08:04:05 +0000"
)
```

I want to make a new array from this array with the objects of today's date (Aug 12)

My code:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSDate *firstDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
[components setMonth:0];
[components setDay:1];
[components setYear:0];
NSDate *secondDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:firstDate options:0];

NSPredicate *firstPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startDate > %@", firstDate];
NSPredicate *secondPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startDate < %@", secondDate];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstPredicate, secondPredicate, nil]];

NSMutableArray *results = [newDate filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

But it gives me error when creating "result":

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSDate 0x72a0ee0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key startDate.'
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well, for starters, you are making up a completely fictional property called "startDate."  What exactly are you attempting to do with your first and second predicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one..

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareDateOnly:(NSDate *)otherDate {
    NSUInteger dateFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
    NSDateComponents *selfComponents = [gregorianCalendar components:dateFlags fromDate:self];
    NSDate *selfDateOnly = [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents:selfComponents];

    NSDateComponents *otherCompents = [gregorianCalendar components:dateFlags fromDate:otherDate];
    NSDate *otherDateOnly = [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents:otherCompents];
    return [selfDateOnly compare:otherDateOnly];
}
```

Comment: I don't know exactly if you have asked this but if you only want to compare the date component of a NSDate you have to use NSCalendar and NSDateComponents to remove the time component.

Something like this should work as a category for NSDate:

Answer (score 1):

Try with following code.

array={"2013-08-11 20:26:11 +0000",
    "2013-08-11 20:26:11 +0000",
    "2013-08-12 06:22:38 +0000",
    "2013-08-12 07:24:14 +0000",
    "2013-08-12 08:04:05 +0000"};/////Example.

```
NSMutableArray *newArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSDate *today=[NSDate date];

NSComparisonResult result;
//has three possible values: NSOrderedSame,NSOrderedDescending, NSOrderedAscending

for(int i=0;i<array.count;i++)
{
result = [today compare:[array objectAtIndex:i]];


if(result==NSOrderedDescending)//////If matches with today's date.
{
   [newArray addObject:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
}
}
```